# Can't update access database threw asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

my access database wont update with this code. what seems to be the problem?
i have tried a lot of methods for updating my access database with no sucsess
please guys some help.

```
protected void Btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem RI in rptEdit.Items)
        {
            Label id = RI.FindControl("Pid") as Label;
            TextBox prdname = RI.FindControl("prdname") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdprice = RI.FindControl("prdprice") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdshortdesc = RI.FindControl("prdshortdesc") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdtype = RI.FindControl("prdtype") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdbrand = RI.FindControl("prdbrand") as TextBox;

            int updated;
            string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Table.accdb";
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string updSql = @"UPDATE ProductList SET
                    Pname = '" + prdname.Text + "' WHERE Pid = ?";
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(updSql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = prdname.Text;
                    updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The update query parameters don't make sense. Have a look at [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access).

Comment: Can you help me fix my code?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Ok, I will try to fix it, and I will update you soon. Thank you.

Comment: not working....

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. Edit your original question with other things you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ? style parameters in your SQL.

```
string sql = @"UPDATE ProductList SET Pname = ? WHERE Pid = ?";
```

Then just make sure you add your parameters in the same order in your code that they appear in the SQL.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(prdName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(id.Text));
```

You need to make sure the type of the variable being added in C# matches the type in the DB (in terms of text or number). Then it can be properly quoted or not as needed.